# Eclipse - Override automatically generated source from other source folder

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I have a project set-up with two source folders. Folder1 is an automatically generated set of java source files that I don't want to touch, Folder2 is a folder with slight edits of some of these files.

What I want the compiler to do is ignoring the files from Folder1 if there's an edited file in Folder2.

I tried finding how to turn off the "Type X is already defined" error in Eclipse, but I can't find it under Errors/Warnings in the settings. I assume turning off this error and setting the order correctly will make the compiler use the correct file of the two.

What I don't want, obviously, is excluding all duplicates in Folder1 from the build path by hand. I don't necessarily want you to fix my set-up, if there's a better way entirely to set this up, feel free to suggest. Do remember that whatever happens, all of the sources need to end up in the same bin folder, due to a path complexity I can't solve. I'd also like to stay clear of build scripts if at all possible.

Comment: You can select a particular file and exclude it from build.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean by "I don't want to exclude every file by hand"

Comment: No problem :)

It's a solution I AM considering, but it's about 100 files, so it'd be tedious I reckon

Comment: Sounds like a fundamentally broken project to me. Don't know if it can be done without coding Eclipse; easier to run a script, or fix it.

Comment: Sure, that's the question, how would you "fix it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two projects:
prj1 has only Folder1 and
prj2 has only Folder2. prj1 is listed as a required project on prj2. That way sources in Folder2 will override the ones in Folder1.

Answer (score 1):

When this kind of problem occurs to me, I use SVN, I cautiously create a new branch, and work on it.

After, it is up to you to migrate intricated pathes here.

If as Dave Newton said, you can consider it is a broken project, this may help you to save it.

Comment: The main problem here is that the "Folder1" stuff is automatically generated and regenerated for each version of the app. I can see how an SVN set-up would work and even considered it, but with the generated sources changing each release, that would basically mean that all involved files would have to be committed for every release, making it a broken version control system, which is just a  small step up from a broken project. Good answer though

Comment: No certain to be exactly in the concerned project, but after each regenerated Folder1, you can *merge* it in your branch. HTH

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement of:

```
...ignore files from Folder1 if there is an edited file in Folder2...
```

You need an overlay/union file system in which there is

```
a RO mount that contains your original file set 
a RW mount that initially contains nothing
an overlay/union mount for use by an application
```

When an application updates a file, the file system saves the file to the RW location.  The file system always hides a file in the RO location once a file by the same name exists in the RW location.

The concept will sound strange at first.

Ask google to show you "What is an overylay filesystem" and "What is a union filesystem" to learn more.

Comment: Sure, that's exactly what I'm trying to do here, inside Eclipse. Your idea is interesting, but doesn't work with a code project really, as it isn't something that's usable with version control. The functionality you describe is what I'm trying to achieve in Eclipse.